# Checkout - get shipping methods in custom component

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, shipping-methods, uicomponent

Magento 2.0.1.

I have created custom component in checkout, and I want to get inside its js file list of active shipping methods and preselect one of them, according to configuration passed via custom `CheckoutConfigProvider`.
My component is placed in `shipping step` node children array.

Problem is getting shipping method list. Firstly I tried to use as dependency `magento2/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-service.js` and then use method `getShippingRates`, which actually is used inside `magento2/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js` and there it returns shipping methods list. Unfortunately, my js it returns an empty array.

Also, I tried to move my component into children array of `shipping adrress` node, but it did not help.

In both places, my component js is loaded before `shipping.js` and returns empty methods array. Has anyone tried to work with shipping methods during checkout loading?

Comment: Any Screenshot?

Comment: Screenshots of what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at:

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/cart/shipping-rates.js**. We can get the shipping rates list:

```
shippingRates: shippingService.getShippingRates(),
```

But, we need to observe the value with [**`initObservable`**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157985/how-does-magento-2s-initobservable-function-work). For example:

```
    /**
     * @override
     */
    initObservable: function () {
        var self = this;

        this._super();

        this.shippingRates.subscribe(function (rates) {
            self.shippingRateGroups([]);
            _.each(rates, function (rate) {
                var carrierTitle = rate['carrier_title'];

                if (self.shippingRateGroups.indexOf(carrierTitle) === -1) {
                    self.shippingRateGroups.push(carrierTitle);
                }
            });
        });

        return this;
    },
```

Comment: You mean that I need to override this js or I can I achieve it in my custom component/module without overriding.

Comment: We don't need to override this js. You can follow the same logic for our custom js.