# How to restrict Shipping Methods

Tags: magento2, cart, shipping-methods

I need to restrict Shipping Method options based on custom collection data in Magento 2.

[image: if-satisfies]

I have added a condition to the below file:

```
<!-- ko if: ($data != "Free Shipping") -->
<!-- ko-->
```

But I want to add another condition:

```
if($customerlevel >= $targetlevel){
  # free shipping
}else{
  # no free shipping
}
```

How can I get custom collection data in knockout HTML template to put condition like above?

`/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/cart/shipping-rates.html`

```
<form id="co-shipping-method-form" data-bind="blockLoader: isLoading, visible: isVisible()">
    <p class="field note" data-bind="visible: (shippingRates().length <= 0)">
        <!-- ko text: $t('Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time')--><!-- /ko -->
    </p>
    <fieldset class="fieldset rate" data-bind="visible: (shippingRates().length > 0)">
        <dl class="items methods" data-bind="foreach: shippingRateGroups">
        <!-- ko if: ($data != "Free Shipping") -->
            <dt class="item-title"><span data-bind="text: $data"></span></dt>
            <dd class="item-options" data-bind="foreach: { data:$parent.getRatesForGroup($data), as: 'method' }">
                <div data-bind="css: {'field choice item': available, 'message error': !available} ">
                    <!-- ko ifnot: (available) -->
                    <div data-bind="text: error_message"></div>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko if: (available) -->
                    <input type="radio"
                           class="radio"
                           data-bind="
                                click: $parents[1].selectShippingMethod,
                                checked: $parents[1].selectedShippingMethod,
                                attr: {
                                        value: carrier_code + '_' + method_code,
                                        id: 's_method_' + carrier_code + '_' + method_code
                                        }
                                "/>
                    <label class="label" data-bind="attr: {for: 's_method_' + carrier_code + '_' + method_code}">
                        <!-- ko text: $data.method_title --><!-- /ko -->
                        <each args="element.getRegion('price')" render="" />
                    </label>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </div>
            </dd>
        <!-- /ko -->
        </dl>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: based on customer collection data Magento 2. Can u explain in details?

Comment: i was just edited question

Comment: $customerlevel & $targetlevel both customer attributes or fields?

Comment: both are custom collection data

Comment: Maybe you will find some inspiration here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198444/checkout-get-shipping-methods-in-custom-component

Answer (score 1):

The first thing: The template which you paste here is only part from Cart - not from chcekout.

Checkout template for shipping methods you will find here

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

In Checkout you have access to Quote object and to customer-data saved in localStorage.

So I thnik that you should extend a Quote about your custom attributes or add them to customer object in localStorage.

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/quote.js
>   vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js

When you will have yours attributes in Knockout.JS, you have 2 possiblities:

1. Better and more complicated to implement. Change the ShippingRates collections, which contains array with all shippings methods. Depends on your attribute add or remove Free Shipping from this collection.
2. In template hide your method when your condition is true. You can use 
   **carrier_code** to detect a freeshipping and implement Knockout *'if'* with your custom attributes or use `data-bind="visible: your_condition"` on any div element