# magento 2 : How to use observable.publishOn or observable.subscribeTo with ko js

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I am getting following error while use `publishOn` and `subscribeTo` method of `knockoutjs`

> TypeError: ko.observable(...).publishOn is not a function

Here is the script

**jsfile1.js**

```
define([
'jquery',
'ko'
], function ($, ko) {
  return component.extend({
      this.id = ko.observable().publishOn('test');
  },
  defaults: {
      template: 'Custom_Test/product/view/test1',
  },

  )
})
```

**jsfile2.js**

```
define([
'jquery',
'ko'
], function ($, ko) {
  return component.extend({
      this.aid = ko.observable().SubscribeTo('test');
  },
  defaults: {
      template: 'Custom_Test/product/view/test2',
  },

  )
})
```

Please help me to sort it out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these methods are from a plugin that isn't included in M2, see https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox for more info.

Also, a function named `initObservable` has been created for setting up observables. See [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157985/how-does-magento-2s-initobservable-function-work) for more info.

Comment: ManyThanks @BenCrook., Issue has been fixed by https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox plugin

Answer (score 1):

Have you extended (created) those methods? they don't exist by default; http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html

You should set your value like this:

```
ko.observable(this.id).publishOn('test');
```

Currently you are setting (publishing) nothing on `test`

Comment: I have added as mention in by `var shouter = new ko.subscribable()`. It is setting properly but unable to get on antoher js. I have updated the question

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: Shouldn't observables be created with the M2 `initObservable` function?

Comment: Perhaps, I'm not aware of this. But in source (for example /Users/tommyquissens/sites/wegro/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js) they create the isLoading observable straight away.

Comment: From what I can tell it doesn't really matter, I like to do things the Magento way but it doesn't seem like they use it consistently themselves.

Comment: Consistency isn't their forte :-)